# BinaryFormatter bytes usage

Tags: c#, serialization

I was playing with BinaryFormatter and started to serialize things.
Used to serialize large things like List, Arrays etc and wasn't contemplating about bytes used cause i know there is some magic bytes, type definition, data value and maybe other things I can't imagine.
F.e:

```
int[] values = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

results 48 bytes long.
Then something happened and stucked my brain, I serialized an int and it's 58 bytes long.

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(stream, 5);
```

Am I missing something? Cause larger data(Array of class for example) uses less memory.
Why does a basic type need all these bytes?
Whole int ( Int32 struct) gets serialized? int[] with 5 values still needed less bytes.

Comment: Looks like `BinaryFormatter` has a more compact way of serializing arrays of primitives than it does primitives themselves. Compare: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b1vVUR . See how it needs to serialize the primitive as its fully-qualified name, and the names of its members, whereas the array gets a more compact encoding. Don't ever expect `BinaryFormatter` to produce a *compat* binary representation of your type: it isn't designed for that. In fact just don't use it, as it's impossible to make secure, and has been deprecated

Comment: As a general comment regarding using BinaryFormatter, it is known to be fragile, insecure, slow and and rather inefficient. There are better alternatives, like Protobuf, json, bson, etc.

Comment: c# has hidden types and part of the structure.  So you array has 5 integers (30 bytes) plus 28 bytes of overhead which includes the variable types.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you hexdump the MemoryStream for the array you get:

```
array 
00000 : 00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  .....????.......
00016 : 00 0F 01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 08 01 00 00 00 02  ................
00032 : 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 0B  ................
```

and for the int value you get:

```
value 
00000 : 00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  .....????.......
00016 : 00 04 01 00 00 00 0C 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 49 6E  .......System.In
00032 : 74 33 32 01 00 00 00 07 6D 5F 76 61 6C 75 65 00  t32.....m_value.
00048 : 08 05 00 00 00 0B                                ......
```

The byte at position 0x17 is most likely the "what to expect next" indicator because for a long that byte remains 04.

I don't have to explain what the difference is. For arrays there is an optimized serialization scheme for known types. For anything else the serializer includes the typename and an internal implementation detail (`m_value` in this case) that is probably the actual value backing field for that type.

As indicated by JonasH in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68468312/binaryformatter-bytes-usage#comment121004528_68468312) and similar to an answer I wrote earlier [C# BinaryFormatter bytes orde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041390/c-sharp-binaryformatter-bytes-orde/48042351#48042351) don't wonder too much about what the BinaryFormatter does and foremost don't rely on its behavior to be stable across versions of the Framework or even version of your assembly (if you serialize your own types in this format) and with stable I mean: being able to deserialize later what you serialized today.